# Groovy: No such file exception but file is there ? Copying files on crossplateforms

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, groovy, copy

I have an issue with Groovy\Jenkins when trying to copy files

The code I use is the following:

```
public void copy(String sources, String destination) {

    Path source = Paths.get( join(this.script.WORKSPACE, sources) );
    Path target = Paths.get( join(this.script.WORKSPACE, destination) );

    Files.copy(source, target)

}
```

`this.script.WORKSPACE` is Jenkins workspace, and if this workspace is `C:\Jenkins\Workspace\MyBranch` and the sources are `binaries\mybinary.dll` then the join function will return:

```
C:\Jenkins\Workspace\MyBranch\mybinary.dll
```

At execution I receive the following error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Y:\Jenkins\workspace\MyBranch\mybinary.dll
```

However the file is there, on the agent.

The thing is that I was using xcopy because I had to copy only on windows target (and it works without any issue, I isolated the change to the copy function, and now the windows copy is failling).

But now I have also to copy on redhat plateforms.

So I am looking for a crossplateform solution

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

So I found out this is a Jenkins related issue. Actually the pipeline is executed on the master, not the agent, so the file is looked for on the master, on which it does not exist.

I will have to use either sh scripts, or the jenkins stash function but it does not seem like I can have a cross plateform code here.